# fetch video from firebase

Tags: flutter, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to stream video directly from firebase cloud and I have somehow managed to print the video URL  in console but when I tried to assign the value to videoplayercontroller all I am getting is blank screen. Here is the code below:

```
class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
    }
    
    class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
      VideoPlayerController _controller;
      Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
      String newURL;
    
      Future<String> getVideos() async {
        final videos = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').get();
    
        for (var video in videos.docs) {
          final newUrl = video.get('url');
          final name = video.get('name');
          print(name);
          newURL =await newUrl;
        }
    print(newURL);
        return newURL;
      }
    
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        getVideos();
        try {
          _controller = VideoPlayerController.network('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUjPXXTeTFo'
             );
          _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
          _controller.setLooping(true);
          _controller.setVolume(1);
          super.initState();
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        _controller.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Video Demo',
            home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Video Demo"),
              ),
              body: FutureBuilder(
                future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return Center(
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                        child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                      _controller.pause();
                    } else {
                      _controller.play();
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Icon(
                    _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow),
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't play YouTube videos directly, please see the following [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23360#issuecomment-431856372)

Although you can make a workaround using [Youtube Explode](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_explode_dart) package to get the redirects from Youtube and obtain where the real video url is, here's an example I used in my app, although I grabbed from searching from this forum:

```
Future<String> extractVideoUrl(String url) async {
    final extractor = YoutubeExplode();
    final videoId = convertUrlToId(url);
    final streamManifest =
        await extractor.videos.streamsClient.getManifest(videoId);
    final streamInfo = streamManifest.muxed.withHighestBitrate();
    extractor.close();
    return streamInfo.url.toString();
  }


String convertUrlToId(String url, {bool trimWhitespaces = true}) {
    assert(url?.isNotEmpty ?? false, 'Url cannot be empty');
    String _url;
    if (!url.contains('http') && (url.length == 11)) return url;
    if (trimWhitespaces) {
      _url = url.trim();
    } else {
      _url = url;
    }

    for (final exp in [
      RegExp(
          r'^https:\/\/(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$'),
      RegExp(
          r'^https:\/\/(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/embed\/([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$'),
      RegExp(r'^https:\/\/youtu\.be\/([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$')
    ]) {
      final Match match = exp.firstMatch(_url);
      if (match != null && match.groupCount >= 1) return match.group(1);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Once you get url, you will be able to stream the video.

Comment: hello sir ! I hope you are doing well, actually I have posted 2 -3 queries on stack but no one is replying. I need your help you are the only person who have helped me solving my queries , I am new to flutter Please help me out. I will waiting for your response . Thank you.